# Mysql to postgres Migration pgloader not working - No data imported No Errors

Tags: data-migration, pgloader

I tried the following command and it returns no errors but the data is not imported in my postgres database.

Database is already created in Postgres.

`pgloader mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1/db_name postgresql://pgloader_pg:password@127.0.0.1/pg_db_name`

This is the result:

`LOG pgloader version "3.6.7~devel"`

[image: Screenshot of pgloader error]

I am not sure what is the issue.